# Unknown entity bean class: null, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

My app is a java ee application with jpa and ejb. Everything worked perfect but i tried to run it today and nothing works. The exception in the title is the reason it doesn't work. All the entities are marked with the @Entity annotation. I read some similar topics but i can't understand how to fix it!

Comment: Please update question to include what Java EE server, JPA provider and their versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using version control, *as you should be* (even [git](http://git-scm.com/) with no remote), then just compare the version where "Everything worked perfect" with the one from today.

Without a bit more info, I'd guess you have a listed class (in persistence.xml or orm.xml) that no longer exists or has been refactored to a different package.

Here are three things that might help you track it down.

**1. Turn up the JPA provider's logging.**

For EclipseLink it would be: `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />`

**2. Check the fields of the classes marked with `@Entity`.**

Any field that isn't in the following list must have an `@Entity` or `@Embeddable` annotation. (Note: enums field must state how their persisted, e.g. `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`)

- Primitive types: boolean, byte, short, char, int, long, float and double.
- Equivalent wrapper classes from package java.lang:
- Boolean, Byte, Short, Character, Integer, Long, Float and Double.
- java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigDecimal.
- java.lang.String.
- java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar,
- java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp.

(source: [objectdb](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Simple_Java_Data_Types_))

**3. Check your persistence.xml**

Do you have `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>`?
If so then change it to `false` and if that works then just find the unlisted class(es) in your IDE.

If classes are listed, are they all still present?  With the exact same packages?

Comment: I was forced to delete and recreate all the beans in the app and now it works. Thanks nonetheless !!

Answer (score 0):

***"Unknown Entity bean class"***

this message occurs when entities are not loaded correctly.
Some of the Eclipselink versions such as 2.7.1  has some bugs that fixed at newer versions such as 2.7.5.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957198/eclipselink-entities-not-loaded/59550493#59550493) as another problem such as yours.